# Select intersecting times from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table is as follows:

```
ShiftID, StoreName, StartDate, EndDate, StartTime, EndTime, ShiftNo.
```

I need to select all shifts that intersect e.g Say there are 2 shifts in a day (ShiftNo. column), if shift number 2 starts before shift number 1 ends then both shifts should appear in the result set.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, having dates and times in separate columns is not useful for this.  So, let's combine them.  This may require adjusting the data types:

```
with s as (
      select s.*,
             (cast(startDate as datetime) + starttime) as startdatetime,
             (cast(endDate as datetime) + endtime) as enddatetime
      from shifts s
     )
select s.*
from s
where exists (select 1
              from s s2
              where s.startdatetime < s2.enddatetime and
                    s.enddatetime > s2.startdatetime
             );
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot